# Unable to stream pdf from laravel 5.5

Tags: php, filesystems, laravel-5.6

I have tried streaming a pdf in the browser but it still tells me i am passing a string as a parameter.

```
public function cv($id){


    $user = new user;
    $cv = $user->where('id', $id)->firstOrfail()->Publicprofile->cv_path;

    return response()->file(Storage::get($cv));
}
```

and when i try passing in the name of the file and path it tells me file does not exist

```
return response()->file($cv);
```

here is my filesystem config settings

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

and here is the value the **$cv** variable returns

```
"public/cv/61520610986.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution required that I provide an absolute path using the

```
Public_path() method
```

ended up doing this:

```
public function streamCV($id){

    $user = new user;
    $cv = $user->where('id', $id)->firstOrfail()->Publicprofile->cv_path;
    $cv ="storage". ltrim($cv, 'public');

    return response()->file(public_path($cv));
}
```